# PropType for component prop ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Trying to get a clear answer on how to assign propTypes for React Components passed as a prop.

Is it even necessary that I check this prop type, and if so, how would I go about using proptypes for the following exapmle:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import styles from "./NavIcons.module.css";

function NavIcons(props) {
  return (
      <div className={styles.navIcons}>{props.children}</div>
  );
}

NavIcons.propTypes = {
  children: // WHAT GOES HERE?
};

export default NavIcons;
```

Comment: You can read about PropTypes in the react docs https://en.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html. In your example you can probably use `children: PropTypes.node.isRequired`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be one or more `nodes` -

```
NavIcons.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
    PropTypes.node
  ]),
};
```